# How to make html input tag accept xlsm?

Tags: html

Im trying to accept .xlsm file using the input tag.. but i able to accept xlsx only
Here is my html

```
 <input type="file"
       accept="image/png, image/jpeg, application/pdf, application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
       ng-maxlength="100"
       required />
```

What should I add to the "accept" to allow me to upload .xlsm file ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if this works for you!

```
<input type="file"
   accept=".xl*">
   ng-maxlength="100"
   required 
/>
```

Comment: Please note that this will let the user send any file extension starting with xl https://fileinfo.com/filetypes/x#:~:text=xla . Please note that there should also be server-side validation as people can update the HTML in inspect!

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?
`application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12`

```html
<input type="file"
       accept="image/png, image/jpeg, application/pdf, application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12"
       ng-maxlength="100"
       required />
```